# Live search table with PHP and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i'm making an html table that pulls from a database and displays the entries, with a live search function. everything seems to be in place correctly as far as i can tell, but the table doesn't populate at all, and the search doesn't work.

here is the search function php page:

```
<?php

    require_once '../../php/db.php';

    // Output HTML formats
    $html = '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td class="small">dNameString</td>';
    $html .= '<td class="small">phoneString</td>';
    $html .= '<td class="small">companyString</td>';
    $html .= '<td class="small">billingString</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';

    //Get the search
    $search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
    $search_string = $conn->real_escape_string($search_string);

    // Check if length is more than 1 character
    if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {

         //Insert Time Stamp for complete searches
        $time = "UPDATE query_data SET timestamp=now() WHERE name='" .$search_string. "'";

        //Count how many times a query occurs 
        $query_count = "UPDATE query_data SET querycount = querycount +1 WHERE name='" .$search_string. "'";

        //Query
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE clientDisplayName LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

        //Timestamp entry of search for later display
        $time_entry = $conn->query($time);

        //Count how many times a query occurs
        $query_count = $conn->query($query_count);

        // Do the search
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $result_array[] = $results;
        }

         // Check for results
        if (isset($result_array)) {
            foreach ($result_array as $result) {
                // Output strings and highlight the matches
                $d_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b>".$search_string."</b>", $result['clientDisplayName']);
                $d_phone = $result['clientPhNumber'];
                $d_comp = $result['clientCompanyName'];
                $d_street = $result['clientBillingStreet'];

                // Replace the items into above HTML
                $o = str_replace('dNameString', $d_name, $html);
                $o = str_replace('phoneString', $d_phone, $o);
                $o = str_replace('companyString', $d_comp, $o);
                $o = str_replace('billingString', $d_street, $o);

                // Output it
                echo($o);
            }
        } else {
             // Replace for no results
             $o = str_replace('dNameString', '<span class="label label-danger">No Names Found</span>', $html);
             $o = str_replace('phoneString', '', $o);
             $o = str_replace('companyString', '', $o);
             $o = str_replace('billingString', '', $o);

             // Output
             echo($o);
        }

    }

?>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

$(".tablesearch").hide();
// Search
function search() {
    var query_value = $('input#clientDisplayName').val();
    if(query_value !== ''){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../php/search.php",
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("table#resultTable tbody").html(html);
            }
        });
    }return false;    
}

$("input#clientDisplayName").live("keyup", function(e) {
    // Set Timeout
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

    // Set Search String
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    // Do Search
    if (search_string == '') {
        $(".tablesearch").fadeOut(300);
    }else{
        $(".tablesearch").fadeIn(300);
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    };
});

});
```

And here is the actual table in html:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <p>Type a name to begin searching</p>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" name="search" role="form" method="POST" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
                        <div class="input-group col-sm-11">
                            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by name..." autocomplete="off"/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnSearch">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </span>
                                </button> </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row mt">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="content-panel tablesearch">

                    <section id="unseen">
                        <table id="resultTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th class="small">Name</th>
                                    <th class="small">Phone</th>
                                    <th class="small">Company</th>
                                    <th class="small">Address</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </section>

                </div><!-- /content-panel -->
            </div><!-- /col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /row -->


        <div class="row mt">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3>Top Searches</h3>
                <p>These results are ranked by popularity in the query_data table. Each time the complete name is entered in the search, a +1 is registered and incremented.</p>
                <div class="content-panel">

                    <section id="unseen">
                        <table id="resultTable-topsearch" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th class="small">Name</th>
                                    <th class="small">Company</th>
                                    <th class="small">Zip</th>
                                    <th class="small">City</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody><?php include 'php/top_search.php' ?></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </section>

                </div><!-- /content-panel -->
            </div><!-- /col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /row -->
```

I've been tearing hair over this, can anybody help?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your server log or browser console?

Comment: nope, it just doesnt display any entries or anything. the table structure is there,it just doesnt display the entries from the database

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Does your query get called? does it return expected values? etc.

Comment: Oh, and I think you need $("table#resultTable tbody").innerHTML(html);

$("table#resultTable tbody").html(html); return the html of the selected element, it doesn't set it

Comment: the table structure loads, and just wont pull from the database to populate the table. here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/OPq0nNV

Comment: Is your SQL query getting called? Is the output correct if you run it manually?

Comment: dg4220, i tried changing it to inner, and it didnt change anything. thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: i executed the sql statement on phpmyadmin, and it ran just fine and returned a user, so maybe something with the search_string variable

Comment: Two things: have your php file echo $query; and see what you get; try that SQL in phpMyAdmin. Also, after your 'success' in ajax, what's the value of html? Anything? Try console.log(response) or alert(html). I think you need to use 'o' rather than hmtl since you change your string variable to $o before returning the result. So if not alert(html) see what alert(o) gives you. (Keep innerHTML in place)

Comment: so when i echo $result, and $o, it returns nothing, its just blank. and im starting to notice that my button for searching isnt refreshing or anything. im starting to think its a problem with my triggers.js not executing correctly.

Comment: That would be a problem - but do try outputting $query if that's broken it would cause $result and $o to fail even if your trigger.js is working

Comment: this is just insanity to me, i cant understand why it wont return ANYTHING. im using a dbconnect file thats used for other parts of the site, so it cant be the connection...the statement executes just fine in phpmyadmin to pull the entries, and my js is set to show it in the table body, yet NOTHING shows up. im gonna cry fam :'(